# LinearProgressIndicator doesn't fit parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart, linearprogressindicator

I'm trying to give the `LinearProgressIndicator` width for the available space using `LayoutBuilder` but it throws an exception:

[image: exception image]

Here's my code for regenerating the issue:

```
Positioned(
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      top: 328,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 141,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                          color: const Color(0xFFFDFDFD),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          ),
                          shadows: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color(0x26000000),
                              blurRadius: 20,
                              offset: Offset(0, -1),
                              spreadRadius: -7,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                const CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/idiomspic.png'),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 16),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      'Idiomatic expressions III',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xFF424242),
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontFamily: 'Balsamiq Sans',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        const Text(
                                          '34%',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xFF686868),
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        LayoutBuilder(
                                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                                            return Container(
                                              width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                              height: 5,
                                              child: const LinearProgressIndicator(
                                                value: 0.34,
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 19),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Latest activity',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF686868),
                                      fontSize: 9,
                                      fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  'Resume lesson',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF0467C5),
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Balsamiq Sans',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

What should I change to get this working?